# Coredata performance -- shipping prepopulated core data sqlite db for readonly data set

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5

i am thinking to create a pre-populate core data sqlite file and copy to my resources. And use it instead of creating a database from scratch on first run.

My data is readonly and will not be modified by iphone app.

Database will be updated may be once in a month. So is it okay that for updating I get the updated coredata sqlite db via http request and discard the previous one and start using the updated one.
This approach will also save me hassle for migration and other stuff

Please suggest, if this approach seems okay

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea seems ok, but there is one problem.

Files in the main app bundle are readonly, thus you can't update the sqlite file.

What you can do is when you create the coredata store file, check wether the file is in the document director. If it is not there copy the file from the bundle there and then create the managedstore.